# Can't load custom look&feel from JAR file since Java 9

Tags: java, jar, ant, look-and-feel

My Java application uses the [Substance look&feel](https://github.com/kirill-grouchnikov/substance) for its UI. My application is released as `.jar` file, which includes the dependency `.jar` files for the look&feel in its root directory. The Manifest file looks like this:

```
Rsrc-Class-Path: ./ jgoodies-forms-1.4.1.jar jgoodies-common-1.1.1.jar
  netty-3.6.10.Final.jar commons-io-2.4.jar commons-lang-2.6.jar commo
 ns-codec-1.8.jar commons-logging-1.1.1.jar substance-7.1.01.jar tride
 nt-1.4.jar
Class-Path: .
```

The two relevant dependencies here are `substance-7.1.01.jar` and `trident-1.4.jar`. I double-checked that these two files are really located within the `.jar` file of my application.

Now this all worked fine until Java 8. But now since Java 9, loading the look&feel at runtime does not work any longer. It fails with this exception:

```
Can't initialize Swing look&feel.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.pushingpixels.substance.api.skin.SubstanceGraphiteLookAndFeel
```

I have neither changed any of my code, nor the Ant build process. The only difference is the update to Java 9. Any ideas?

PS: It does work fine when I start it from within IntelliJ using Java 9, so it seems to be related to the packaged `.jar` of my application.